# Fantasy book series involving 3 magic stones

Tags: story-identification, magic

Fantasy book series from the 80's and maybe early 90's. Involved 3 magic stones, one in the forehead, 1 over the heart and one in the palm of the 3 main characters.

I can't remember much more of the plot details but I remember them being a great read.

Answer (score 10):

That's [Simon Hawke's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Hawke) (aka Nicholas Valentin Yermakov and J D Masters)'[Wizard](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?2696)' series. 
(Commonly referred to by the title of the first book, '[The Wizard of 4th Street.](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/674252.The_Wizard_of_4th_Street)')

- The young man with the stone (one of three 'Runestones' in the books) on his forehead is Wyrdrune, a Warlock (read that as a low-level wizard; he was a very promising student, at one time, but.. things happened.)
- The girl with one on her palm is Kira, a sexy young thief,
- The mage with one over his heart is [Mordred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordred). 
  (Yes; that Mordred -- From King Arthur's stories.)

Early on, [Merlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin) (again, from King Arthur) helps them, but he is killed off early on...

> only to re-appear and continue to work with them by possessing one of his descendants, a street-tough named Billy.  They don't always get along.

Here are a few of the covers you may recognize.
[image: Wizard of 4th Street] [image: Samurai Wizard]
[image: Wizard of Rue Morgue]

Comment: Wow, I've been trying to remember the name of this series for ***years***!