# Fantasy story with a war and magic usable via stones; main character was trapped in a collapsed mine

Tags: story-identification, books, magical-items

I'm looking for a book, I'm not sure if it was part of a series or a single tome.

I remember that in the story, magic was usable via stones (I'm not sure what kind but it might have been real-life minerals, like quartz), and the main story was very closely tied to a big war.

Two more things I remember is a scene with the main hero and a couple of other guys digging out from a collapsed mine, and the main hero eventually going apeshit over said war and imbuing his body with previously mentioned magic stones.

The stones were not super rare, and both sides of the conflict used them.

Also he was betrayed by his country in the end, because they couldn't pay him or something like that.

Comment: Could it be R.A. Salvatore's [DemonWars saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_DemonWars_Saga) (has a [stone-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_(fictional_world)#Magic) magic system) or Brandon Sanderson's Mistborn series ([metal-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mistborn#Magic) magic)?

Comment: Definitely not DemonWars, and from the plot summary I've just read it's not Mistborn either. I'm definitely going to take a look at Mistborn tho, looks really interesting, thanks!

Comment: I haven't read much by Sanderson, just his Elantris, but it was a damn good book, with an interesting story, an unique setting and well written and alive characters. I should start Mistborn myself as well.

Comment: The "related" links at the right reference SImon Hawke's Wizard series (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76257/fantasy-book-series-involving-3-magic-stones?rq=1). Is that it?

Comment: @Sekhemty Elantris is by far his *worst* book. If you like it, you'll love his other stuff.

Comment: Some of David Gemmell's fantasy novels featured stones of power called Sipstrassi. The scenes you describe don't ring any bells but he wrote a LOT of books.

Comment: @Sam Unfortunately it's not it. As far as i remember these stones were not super rare, and both sides of conflict used them.

Comment: @Moriarty Unfortunately it's not that either :(

Comment: Can you provide more information about when you read the book or other characteristics of the book itself (cover art, maybe)?

Comment: Well, this is kind of embarrasing... now i know why i couldn't find it anywhere, and why You guys couldn't help me. Turns it it was probably not even translated to english, and since i last read it i've gotten so used to english (not that i'm good at it :P) that i didn't even think it about it maybe not being translated. Oh well, I'm really sorry :(.
For the interested, the book i was looking for is "Ve službách Klanu" wrtten by Miroslav Žamboch. 
Sorry again and thanks for all the help! :P

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by OP in [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/197360/fantasy-story-with-war-and-magic-usable-via-stones#comment541852_197360), this is a 2013 Czech book by Miroslav Žamboch, entitled *Ve službách Klanu* (which translates into *In services of the clan* if I am to believe [this site on Czech literature](https://www.czechlit.cz/en/author/miroslav-zamboch-en/)).

*All quotes below are courtesy of Google Translate.*

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17671497-ve-slu-b-ch-klanu):

> Herbert Ducatti is a miner. Deep underground, active gems benefit from the wizard's clan. In the Northern Mountains, there is plenty of raw crystal deposits, but it is not easy to harvest - concentrated magic over a few hours burns the brain of every ordinary person. And if it dips deep enough, it's enough for that second. Only sorcerers can survive in the deep. But it's still not the worst ...
>
> Active gems want all clans. And what they all want is usually fighting. Herbert Ducatti just wanted to survive ... At least initially.

[This review](http://www.sarden.cz/2013-04-04-0105/recenze-miroslav-zamboch-ve-sluzbach-klanu) by Martin Stručovský matches several of the plot points OP remembered.

**The main hero and a couple of other guys digging out from a collapsed mine.**

> And if that's not enough, he *[Herbert]* and the rest of the party get stuck in the underground hill, where they have to wait for a few months for bare survival.

**Main hero eventually going apeshit over said war and imbuing his body with previously mentioned magic stones.**

> And so, in fact, Ducatti's transformation and ascension begins. Because if he was before a man, then he returns to the surface and becomes something else. An inhuman, monster who implanted magical stones in his own survival.

**Also he was betrayed by his country in the end, because they couldn't pay him or something like that.**

A couple of reviews here and there mention the book dealing with "zrada" ("betrayal") but I couldn't find a *specific* quote about the character being betrayed by his country.